# How can I use rest api in xaf application?

Tags: rest, xaf

How can we use rest api with an xaf application. I want to connect to rest api and I will use api's methods to connect  to an existing database. How is this possible in xaf?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of resources about making the data available via OData.

See, for instance, [DevExpress's blog post on the subject](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/eaf/archive/2012/12/12/how-to-configure-the-xaf-middle-tier-security-service-and-deploy-it-in-the-cloud-for-further-use-by-desktop-xaf-and-mobile-dxtreme-clients.aspx). Also, Manuel Grundner wrote a [similar blog post](https://biohazard999.github.io/2013/02/22/real-mtier-with-devexpress-part1/).